# RelativeLayout different position of items in editor and on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make footer in `RelativeLayout` with 3 items- one `ImageView`, one `TextView` and a `Button`. I managed to position the `ImageView` at left side of layout and `TextView` near `ImageView` on the left side. However, I cannot properly set position of button at right side of the layout. Positions are different in editor and in my device (when I'm testing it). When I position everything in the way I wanted in editor, after running it on device it doesn't look the same. `Button` that should be on the right side of layout goes off screen.

For example [this](http://prntscr.com/icujnm) is what I see in editor, and [this](http://prntscr.com/icus3d) is what I see on device. If I move button in editor, on position where it should be, [like this](http://prntscr.com/icuss7), then it goes off screen on device, [like this](http://prntscr.com/icut8g).

I also tried using `LinearLayout`, `gravity`, `layout_gravity`, `weight` and different combinations of padding and margins but i just can't get it to work, I don't understand where problem is.

Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/help" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="help"
        android:textColor="@color/mainWhite" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/Continue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full layout should look like this. You need to use `layout_alignParentLeft` and `layout_alignParentRight` properly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/question_icon"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/help" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/question_icon"
        android:text="Help"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/Continue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in right button

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/helpButton"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
```